# HTTP "Don't execute!" Header

Tags: http, http-headers, xss

On my website, files can be shared by URLs like

"/file/file_id",

and the server sends back *exactly* the file contents with the *filename* being specified too.

I guess I should do something with the Content-Type header. If I say

`Content-Type: "image"`
Firefox gladly executes html files too. It seems to be solved by

`Content-Type: "image/jpeg"`

For one I think having to just say "I'm an image!" should be sufficient by standards. For example with a typo(leaving off "jpeg") I could exploit my whole site. Plus now I have to look after all common image types and implement headers for them.

Secondly it would be great if there was a header for this(DO NOT EXECUTE). Is there one?

I looked at some "X-XSS-Protection" header but it looks like something else only IE understands anyway. Sorry if this was answered somewhere, I have not found it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Makes browsers respect the `Content-Type` you send, so if you're careful to only send known-safe types (e.g. *not* SVG!), it'll be fine.

There's also CSP that might be a second line of defence:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
```

Sites that are very careful about security host 3rd party content on a completely different top-level domain (to get same-origin policy protection and avoid cookie injection through compromised subdomains).

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally there have been many ways to circumvent the different protections. As such, a full defense relies on multiple mechanisms (defense-in-depth).

Most larger companies solve this by hosting such files on custom domain (e.g. googleusercontent.com). If an attacker is able to execute script on such a domain, at least that does not give XSS access to the main web site.

X-Content-Type-Options is a non-standard header, and was up until very recently not supported in Firefox, but it is still a part of the defense. It's possible to construct files which are valid in many formats (I have a file that is a "valid" gif, html, javascript and pdf).

Images can normally be served directly (with x-content-type-options).

Other files can be served with content-type text/plain, while serving others with "Content-Disposition: attachment" to force a download instead of showing them in the browser.